# how can i select current li element div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create submenu the only porblem that i have  is the submenu should have to be below the main menu not each of main menu li. something like this

[my submenu image](http://www.apnsoft.com/Articles/Images/20120516/Horizontal.gif)

this is my code:

```
    <div id="menu_controller">
            <ul class="menu"> 
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li >
                        <a href="#">
                            کدهای تبلیغاتی
                        </a>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        <li >

                        <a href="#">
                            فروشگاه
                        </a>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        <li>

                        <a href="#">
                            گزارشات
                        </a>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        <li>

                        <a href="#">
                            محصولات
                        </a>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        <li>

                        <a href="#">
                            امور مال
                        </a>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                        <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        <li>

                        <a href="#">
                            پیام ها
                        </a>

                        <div></div>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="#">کل سفارش</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش معلق</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش آماده به ارسال</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش ارسال شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش توزیع شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفارش وصول شده</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">سفار برگشتی</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
</div>
```

and my css code :

```
#menu_controller
{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}
ul.menu
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul.menu li
{
    float:right;
}
ul.menu li:hover {position: absolute;}
ul.menu li:hover ul{display:block; position: absolute;}
ul.menu li:hover li
{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;

}
ul.menu li ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: you have not mentioned code for class "ads" in your css

Comment: no it is my second step in my design, after that i want to design evey main menu and set image and so on.

Comment: the only problem i have is i want all submenus take a place under the main menu

Comment: where you apply menu class on html ?

Comment: like what i mentioned [here](http://www.apnsoft.com/Articles/Images/20120516/Horizontal.gif) as you see in this pic all submenu are take place in one place like local and when user hover the us, submenu of us take local submenu place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with some changes, i you can achieve this by some changes like.

```
.menu{
  list-style: none;    overflow:hidden;
}

ul.menu li{
   float:left;
 display:block;
}
```

You can check this working at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GBJp/)

Answer (score 0):

try it !! It may help you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>A dropdown menu </title>
<style>
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px 0;
  background: #adadad url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -110px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
  font: normal 0.5333333333333333em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e7e5e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
  background: #c7c7c7 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
  background: #666666 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
  color: #444;
  border-top: solid 1px  #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background: #adadad url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background: url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a:link {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
* html #cssmenu ul {
  height: 1%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as i mention above i want to set the submenu in one place not right after the each main menu item something like this [click me to see](http://www.apnsoft.com/Articles/Images/20120516/Horizontal.gif)

Comment: Please at first check your code that you have posted.This is not looking like your explanation. Or please post your full code.